# Which IBM Websphere Server could support MAC OS?

Tags: macos, websphere

Recently I'm using IBM Websphere Server for some estimates. Include:
- WebSphere AS Community Edition V2.0.0.1
- WebSphere AS Community Edition V2.1
- WebSphere AS v6.x
- WebSphere Portal Server v6.x
- WebSphere AS v7.0
but I'm really whether all of them could be supported by MAC OS X 10.6 or 10.7. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the non-community editions it's fairly easy. There is no OS X support at all. WebSphere 6.1/7 links below. For further details just search the vendor site. If you must select a  commercial product I wonder why you do not consider WebSphere 8 as it supports JavaEE 6?

[WebSphere 6.1 System Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27007642)

[WebSphere 7 System Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27012369)

[WebSphere Community Edition](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/community/sysreq/)

Comment: thank you. Need community editions because of some historical reason.

Comment: Added the link to WebSphere CE

Answer (score 2):

[WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile V8.5](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/wasdev/entry/download?lang=en) support Mac OS X but only for development, production is not supported by IBM.